# Connection between ARC Welder and Google Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, google-chrome-arc

I have an APK-package that I have installed in Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits with the help of ARC Welder. The app just works fine as long as the temporary files made by ARC Welder "com.bankid.bus-6230.apk_export_VZxwa" remains in the same folder as they were created (i.e. ~/.BID/com.bankid.bus-6230.apk_export_VZxwa).

If I delete this directory or move it the app can't be started, so the question is where (and why) does Google Chrome keep track of this directory?

I've been running "cat `ls -R` | grep *.BID*" all over Google Chromes directories trying to find where the link backwards to this "installation directory" is to be found, but with no success.

Is it a binary link? Hidden in database? Any information is much appreciated.

/Paul